# Adding a .join to an observable array

Tags: arrays, foreach

I have an array in which i have a foreach loop to display items from the array. But i also want to add a comma after each item if there are more than one. What is suggested that i use? a `join` function?

```
<div data-bind="foreach: singers">
     <span data-bind="text: singerName"></span>
</div>


var self = { singers: ko.observableArray()}

singersList = function(viewModal, song){
   if(Array.isArray(song.singers)){
         viewModal.singers(song.singers.map(function(singer){
         var result = new singerVm(singer);
         return result.join(', ');
       }));
    }
};
```

When i added the join, i got a console error stating: join is not a funtion(..) and i am not sure what that means or why.

How can i properly add the `.join` so that i could get  the list of singers separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var energy = fruits.join();
```

result will be

```
Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
```

so if you translate your results into an array, simply call join() on it

Comment: Whenever i try adding `.join(', ')` i get a console error message stating: `.join is not a function(...)`

Comment: You may need to convert the contents to a string first

Comment: how would i do that with the structure i currently have?

Comment: return new singerVm(singer) <-- this line, can you convert that into a string?

Comment: I updated my post above and tried doing this but i still get the same error